# What is the correct SQL for a trigger to copy a record to an identical table?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have two tables TABLE1 and TABLE2 with identical structures.  I need a trigger to copy a record after insert from TABLE1 to TABLE2.  What's the proper SQL for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER copy_tab1_tab2_trg AFTER INSERT ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 
       (col1, col2, ..., coln) 
    VALUES 
       (:NEW.col1, :NEW.col2, ..., :NEW.coln);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks!  It was that :NEW part that I was unsure of.

Comment: I wonder if there is no shorter syntax. Repeating all the column names feels redundant. It also means the trigger will be broken once the table structure is altered in any way.